# C Get Unique Identifier From Client (TCP Socket)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, uniqueidentifier

When a client makes a connection to my server via a TCP socket I would like to obtain some form of constant value I can use to identify the client (In C) so I know who they are when they connect to my server in the future. Currently I am using clients Remote IP as a unique identifier, the problem is that a clients IP is not really a constant value and may change depending if they are connected to a VPN or if they have a dynamic IP. So I looked into getting clients MAC address from TCP socket and it seemed as though it was possibly, but very tedious to get it. So I was wondering if there is any other unique values I can pickup from TCP socket and use the value to identify client in future connections?

Comment: What protocol, on top of TCP, are you using? If your packet is going through routers, the Ethernet MAC address will not be the original client's MAC address. So unless you specifically design your protocol this way, or tell each client to connect to a different port, you cannot distinguish them.

Comment: "*I would like to obtain some form of constant value I can use to identify the client* why not just ask the client? Ask the client to register, this way the client could refuse to be identified, which s/he should have the right to.

Comment: @alk at which point the server should also have the right to refuse service...

Comment: @Alnitak the moment it does not know the user or, on registration, if insufficient info is provided.

Answer (score 3):

Have the client generate and send a [GUID / UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), and store it at the client side for subsequent connections.

A 128-bit GUID has a vanishingly small chance of a collision.

APIs to generate them are readily available.

Answer (score 1):

There's no TCP or IP support for this, and going to a lower-level won't help because the peer for those is not likely to be client in question. That means you'll have to look at the higher-level protocols.

For example, if you're using HTTP, you could provide an identifying number in a cookie the client will return to you. Or you could require to the client to provide credentials. Both of these approaches have failure modes.

Answer (score -3):

it depends on your OS where you client program running. For linux/iOS/Windows you can use MAC address or GUIID/UUID, for RTOS based on MCU, it depends on your SDK, MAC address of interface or ID of SPI flash may be used.